# Processing JSON data with Kafka and Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm new in Spark-Streaming and Kafka. With the following code I'm able to consume the Kafka-Messages, which arrive in JSON-Format:

```
JavaDStream<String> jsonline = stream.map(new Function<ConsumerRecord<String,String>, String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> kafkaRecord) throws Exception {
        return kafkaRecord.value();
        }
    });

jsonline.print();
```

Output on console:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1527776685000 ms
-------------------------------------------
{"logtyp":"ERROR","LogTypName":"app.warning.exception","LogZeitpunkt":"Thu May 31 16:24:42 CEST 2018"}
{"logtyp":"ERROR","LogTypName":"app.warning.exception","LogZeitpunkt":"Thu May 31 16:24:44 CEST 2018"}
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1527776690000 ms
-------------------------------------------
{"logtyp":"ERROR","LogTypName":"app.warning.exception","LogZeitpunkt":"Thu May 31 16:24:45 CEST 2018"}
{"logtyp":"ERROR","LogTypName":"app.warning.exception","LogZeitpunkt":"Thu May 31 16:24:46 CEST 2018"}
```

Is it possible to use the "foreachRDD" method to extract the JSON-Fields out of the message?

```
jsonline.foreachRDD...
```

...so I would be able to write each JSON-record to mySQL as followed:

```
insert into my_table (logtyp, logtypname, logzeitpunkt) values ("ERROR", "app.warning.exception", "Thu May 31 16:24:46 CEST 2018");
```

Comment: It is not structured streaming. These are DStreams.